# Navigating to other screen in combination with redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I have the following to Component:

```
RestaurantTemplate :
import React from 'react';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { ImageBackground, StyleSheet, View,TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import { RestaurantData } from '../../Data';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Restaurant from './Restaurant';

class RestaurantOverviewTemplate extends React.Component{
    render() {
        return(
            <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                <Restaurant restaurants={RestaurantData} onPress={this.props.changeToRestaurantId}/>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

const  mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        changeToRestaurantId: (restaurants) => dispatch({ type: 'UPDATE_ID', payload: restaurants })
    }
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(RestaurantOverviewTemplate);
```

Restaurant.js :

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default class Restaurant extends React.Component {
    renderRestaurant = (restaurants) =>{
        return restaurants.map((item, index) => {
            return(
               <View key={ index }>
                  <Button onPress={ () => this.props.onPress(item.id) } title={ item.name }/>
               </View>
            )
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                {this.renderRestaurant(this.props.restaurants)}
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

So I have the `RestaurantTemplate` in which the `Restaurant.js` component is imported. What was my intension is to extract the id of a restaurant and pass it to the `mapDispatchToProps` function that updates a global variable. But my problem is that I want to navigate to another screen when one restaurant is pressed. I thought I could do this like so:

```
<Restaurant 
   restaurants={RestaurantData} 
   onPress={[this.props.changeToRestaurantId, () => this.props.navigation.navigate('RestaurantDetails']}
/>
```

But this won't work. I also can't wrap a TouchableOpacity around the `<Restaurant../>`.
Has anybody an idea how I could fix this?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: did you try with onKeyPress?

Comment: Are you trying to call two functions on `onPress`?

Comment: @DrewReese yes, but I think I can't do this at the same time. I tried to combine them in one function but this didn't work as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as though you want to invoke more than one function in the callback. You can wrap both calls in an anonymous function. Proxy the passed restaurant id to `changeToRestaurantId` and invoke the navigation. This, of course, assumes you have correctly injected `navigation` as a prop into `RestaurantOverviewTemplate` component.

```
<Restaurant
  restaurants={RestaurantData}
  onPress={(id) => {
    this.props.changeToRestaurantId(id); 
    this.props.navigation.navigate('RestaurantDetails');
  }}
/>
```